# React Native Touchable Highlight, open link on press.

Tags: react-native

Simple question, I'm trying to get a link to open whenever the user presses a button, the relevant bits of code are:

```
       _linkPressed: function(url){
            LinkingIOS.openURL(url);
        },

    <View style={styles.contactBox}>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress = {()=> this._linkPressed('www.google.com')}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.contactRow}>
                            <Image
                                source={{uri: 'email.png'}}
                                resizeMode='contain'
                                style={styles.contactIcon} />
                            <Text style={styles.contactText}> Write with your questions </Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

But for some reason the link won't open in the simulator I tried changing the `_linkPressed` function to just log "google.com" to the console and that worked. But I can't seem to grok the LinkingIOS procedure.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to open Mail or Safari?

Comment: I think Mail would be best. I have email, website, twitter and facebook, which I'd like to have them open with whatever their default app was for opening each type of content. But I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add http:// before the link url.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this._linkPressed('http://www.google.com')} >
```

Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/5LAEGQ) example.